# How to disable initial mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery (or pure javascript), if you set a `mouseover` handler, it will be triggered even if the mouse is initially on the element. How to disable that?

For example, look at facebook - place your mouse over the name of a friend in the feed. A hovercard appears. Now refresh the page (without moving the mouse; F5) - the hovercard does not appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `mousemove` instead of `mouseover` ;)

http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` to get that result?